# cardview doesn't work when hardwareAccelerated is false

Tags: android, manifest, hardware-acceleration, cardview

I have set hardwareAccelerated to true in the android manifest but cardview doesn't work then.
what shall I do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem , I had set the hardwareAccelerated to true just for avoiding OOM or Memory leak but after finding some techniques for showing the bitmaps without problem , I put the hardwareAccelerated to false so the cardview worked well then

Answer (score 1):

If you can read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel) article, they mentioned hardware acceleration affecting some UI drawing. So you can disable hardware acceleration for an individual view at runtime instead of describing it in the manifest. You can find sample code snippets in that article. Also, here is the individual view hardware acceleration disable code:

`myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`

Comment: `You can find sample code snippets in that article` links are often changed, removed, updated, etc. it would be best if you could include at least some form of example in your answer, just to help others out in future